# jQuery ajax call to asmx webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

Its been over a year since Ive done this and I cant remember the tips I used to debug this situation.  Got a asp.net page that makes an ajax jquery call to a web service method
Something like this.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //test
        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Common.asmx/GetStateList",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");
                $("[id$='tbOrderState']").autocomplete({
                    source: datafromServer
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });

    })
```

However, when it runs...my breakpoint in the web service code is not hit and i simply get "error" in an alert popup.

What can I check.

Comment: Pop open your developer tools (F12) -- and check the Network tab. You'll see the request and what happened.

Comment: Did you add [ScriptMethod] to your method in the asmx?

Comment: No, not using the [ScriptMethod] attribute, had to look it up.  Looks useful.  Also, I looked at the Network tab with the F12 tool, and sure enough, my call to the web service is getting a 500 error...but yet my breakpoint in the web service isnt getting hit? Its in the same project.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I should have noticed the comments in the web service class attributes // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.  Working now !

Answer (score 0):

To allow your web service to be called from a javascript you need to include this line at the top of your asmx page.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Normally that line is added but commented out.  Just remove the comment and you should be good to go.